# Select Dataframe rows in a date range

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like the following

```
   transaction_no  sales_order  is_delivered dispatch_date  remarks  ....

0          2122.0          1.0          True    06-01-2020      NaN   
1          2122.0          1.0          True    06-01-2020      NaN   
2          2122.0          1.0          True    06-01-2020      NaN   
3          2122.0          1.0          True    06-01-2020      NaN   
4          2122.0          1.0          True    06-01-2020      NaN
```

I want to select rows based on a date range criteria but I am getting the empty dataframe every time

Here's what I did:

```
        dt_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'  

        o_f = datetime.strptime(request.GET['from'], dt_format).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
        o_t = datetime.strptime(request.GET['to'], dt_format).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

        f = datetime.strptime(request.GET['from'], dt_format).replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC).date().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
        t = datetime.strptime(request.GET['to'], dt_format).replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC).date().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")


        allot_df = allot_df[allot_df['dispatch_date'].isin(pd.date_range(f, t))]
```

How can I do that ?
Better yet why is this not working?

Update:
The type of column was `str`
so I changed it to datetime

```
    allot_df['dispatch_date'] = pd.to_datetime(allot_df['dispatch_date'])
    allot_df = allot_df[allot_df['dispatch_date'].isin(pd.date_range(f, t))]
```

But now the whole dataframe comes as the output

Comment: Define "not working". What happens ? If you get an error message, what is it ? My first guess would be that dispatch_date is a string instead of a datetime. Can you verify if that is the case ?

Comment: @ApplePie I get an empty dataframe as a result

Comment: Have you checked that dispatch_date is indeed a date and not a string ?

Comment: @ApplePie I just did and its ` <class 'str'>`, obviously there is a type mismatch. how do I proceed ?

Comment: You can convert dispatch_date using pd.to_datetime()

Comment: @ApplePie please see the update in question

Comment: What are the values of f and t ?

Comment: @ApplePie f ` 2020-09-01 14:09:00+00:00`
 and type of f is `<class 'datetime.datetime'>`

Comment: @RahulSharma what about t ? this would help determine the range.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that just after reading, e.g. calling *pd.read_csv*, without any
type conversion, your DataFrame contains:

```
   transaction_no  sales_order  is_delivered dispatch_date
0          2122.0          1.0          True    06-01-2020
1          2123.0          1.0          True    07-01-2020
2          2124.0          1.0          True    08-01-2020
3          2125.0          1.0          True    09-01-2020
4          2126.0          1.0          True    10-01-2020
```

To check column types run `df.info()` and the result should be something like:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------          --------------  -----  
 0   transaction_no  5 non-null      float64
 1   sales_order     5 non-null      float64
 2   is_delivered    5 non-null      bool   
 3   dispatch_date   5 non-null      object 
dtypes: bool(1), float64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 165.0+ bytes
```

Note *Dtype* for *dispatch_date* column. It is *object* (more precisely,
something other than a number, and actually - a **string**).

A good habit in working with *Pandas* object is to use its native
*datetime* type, and not to use *datetime* module.
This way your code will run substantially faster than if you used other
date/time representation.

So the first step is to convert *dispatch_date* column from *string* to
*datetime*. You can do it calling:

```
df.dispatch_date = pd.to_datetime(df.dispatch_date, dayfirst=True)
```

Now when you print *df*, you will get:

```
   transaction_no  sales_order  is_delivered dispatch_date
0          2122.0          1.0          True    2020-01-06
1          2123.0          1.0          True    2020-01-07
2          2124.0          1.0          True    2020-01-08
3          2125.0          1.0          True    2020-01-09
4          2126.0          1.0          True    2020-01-10
```

The first thing to notice is that now *dispatch_date* is printed in
*year-month-day* format, but for now you may be not sure about its
type. To check this detail, run `df.info()` again and the row
concerning *dispatch_date* should be:

```
3   dispatch_date   5 non-null      datetime64[ns]
```

And if you want to retrieve rows for particular date range, you can e.g.:

- specify both border dates as strings, but also in *year-month-day* format,
- call *df.query*, passing both dates in the query string.

Something like:

```
df.query("dispatch_date.between('2020-01-07', '2020-01-09')")
```

The result is:

```
   transaction_no  sales_order  is_delivered dispatch_date
1          2123.0          1.0          True    2020-01-07
2          2124.0          1.0          True    2020-01-08
3          2125.0          1.0          True    2020-01-09
```

Note that the ending date is **inclusive**, contrary to the way how
you specify *Pandas* slices, where the right border is **exclusive**.

I deliberately didn't go into such details like how to extract both date
strings from your source data, this is another issue and you should cope
with it alone.